# Error al insertar registros con MySQLi con prepared statements

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli, prepared-statements

Publiqué una pregunta ayer, pero surgió otro problema muy similar, ya verifique la conexión con mi base de datos (es correcta), ya hice in "SELECT" de toda mi tabla y respondió correctamente, ya actualice registros y si los actualiza, solo que el id actualizado que me regresa es "0", cuando realmente no es así.

`$id_registro = $sql->insert_id;` esto es lo que siempre retorna "0", por eso no entra en el `if($id_registro > 0)` lo que hace que me de el error.
Ya verifiqué que mi columna tenga `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Ya verifiqué que los datos del form se manden correctamente, honestamente no se donde pueda estar el error. Cualquier información extra que necesiten puedo brindarla.

En la parte del AJAX que se hace un `console.log(data)` intenté retornar la variable de php `die(json_encode($sql));` y todos los campos los regresa como *`NULL`*.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Está es mi conexión con la base de datos.

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '******', '*********');

if($conn->connect_error){
  echo $error -> $conn->connect_error;
}
```

Esté es mi archivo de php

```
include_once "funciones/funciones.php";
$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$id_registro = $_POST['id_registro'];
if ($_POST['registro'] == 'nuevo') { //INICIO-NUEVO
  $opciones = array(
    'cost' => 12
  );
  $password_hashed = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $opciones);
  try {
    $sql = $conn->prepare(" INSERT INTO admins (usuario, nombre, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?) ");
    $sql->bind_param('sss', $usuario, $nombre, $password_hashed);
    $sql->execute();
    $id_registro = $sql->insert_id; //la pregunta pasada me dijeron que insert_id es un método de la conexión no de la sentencia, probé ambas y no funcionó
    if ($id_registro > 0) {
      $respuesta = array(
        'respuesta' => 'exito',
        'id_admin' => $id_registro
      );
    }else{
      $respuesta = array(
        'respuesta' => 'error'
      );
    }
    $sql->close();
    $conn->close();
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
  }
die(json_encode($respuesta));// aqui se regresan valores a ajax
} // FIN-NUEVO

if ($_POST['registro'] == 'actualizar') { // INICIO-ACTUALIZAR
  try {
    if (empty($_POST['password'])) {
      $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE admins SET usuario = ?, nombre = ?, editado = NOW() WHERE id_admin = ? ");
      $stmt->bind_param("ssi", $usuario, $nombre, $id_registro);
    }else{
      $opciones = array(
        'cost'=>12
      );
      $hash_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $opciones);
      $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE admins SET usuario = ?, nombre = ?, password = ?, editado = NOW() WHERE id_admin = ? ");
      $stmt->bind_param("sssi", $usuario, $nombre, $hash_password, $id_registro);
    }
    $stmt->execute();
    if ($stmt->affected_rows) {
      $respuesta = array(
        'respuesta' => 'exito', // esto tiene que corresponder con la respuesta esperada en AJAX
        'id_actualizado' => $stmt->insert_id
      );
    }else{
      $respuesta = array(
        'respuesta' => 'error'
      );
    }
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    $respuesta = array(
      'respuesta' => $e->getMessage()
    );
  }
  die(json_encode($respuesta));
} // FIN-ACTUALIZAR
```

Este es el AJAX al que retorna la respuesta.

```
  $('#guardar-registro').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var datos = $(this).serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
      type: $(this).attr('method'), // post, en este caso
      data: datos, // la variable con todos los datos enviados
      url: $(this).attr('action'), //esto es el archivo php que está más arriba
      dataType: 'json', // el formato de los datos que estamos enviando
      success: function(data) { // data, es lo que regresa el archivo enlazado
        console.log(data);
        var resultado = data;
        if (resultado.respuesta == 'exito') {
          swal(
            'Correcto',
            'Se guardó correctamente',
            'success'
          )
        }else{
          swal(
            'Incorrecto',
            'Hubo un error al crear el administrador',
            'error'
          )
        }
      }
    })
  });
```

EDIT:

Esto es lo que muestra el `SHOW CREATE TABLE admins`:

```
CREATE TABLE `admins` (
 `id_admin` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `usuario` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `nombre` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `password` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
 `editado` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `nivel` int(1) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id_admin`),
 UNIQUE KEY `usuario` (`usuario`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Esto está mal, tal y como se te dijo en la anterior pregunta: `$id_registro = $sql->insert_id;`, porque `insert_id` es un método de la conexión, no de la sentencia, entonces debe ser así: `$id_registro = $conn->insert_id;`, aunque no creo que sea sólo eso lo que está mal, pues dices que te devuelve todo `NULL`, o sea, que tampoco entra en la parte del `else` que otorga la clave `error` al array... aunque lo que muestra tu imagen a la derecha confunde, como si hubieras hecho un `var_dump` de `$stmt` en alguna parte... ¿?

Comment: Ya lo intenté con `$id_registro = $conn->insert_id;` y no funcionó. Lo de la imagen es lo que regresa el AJAX cuando hago un `die(json_encode($sql));`

Comment: **Pues déjalo así, con `$conn`**, porque es la forma correcta. Si lo dejas como lo tienes ahora no haces otra cosa que sumar más errores al código. ¿Y  un `die(json_encode($respuesta));`   qué muestra? Eso es lo que nos interesa, no la sentencia. Y... ve depurando, verifica si la inserción de hace correctamente, puede que la inserción falle.

Comment: Si pongo `die(json_encode($respuesta));` justo antes del `$sql->close()` me regresa `{respuesta: "error"}`

Comment: Entonces vamos a hacer una cosa para saber qué es lo que pasa, agrégale el mensaje del error a la respuesta así: `$respuesta = array(
        'respuesta' => 'error: '.$conn->error
      );` así sabremos a qué se debe que el código esté fallando. Me parece que es un problema con la inserción. Comenta lo que imprime así.

Comment: Retorna esto `{respuesta: "error: Field 'editado' doesn't have a default value"}` , "editado" es una columna en mi tabla...

Comment: Ahora sí estamos hablando claro. En tu tabla `admins` hay un campo que se llama `editado` que al parecer no admite valores `NULL` pero tampoco tiene un valor por defecto. Al no estar entre los campos del `INSERT` la consulta de inserción falla porque no hay valor por defecto para él. Debes modificar la tabla, indicando qué valor por defecto debe tomar ese campo, o permitiendo que admita nulos, o incluirlo en la consulta de inserción dándole un valor. Supongo que ese campo debe ser del tipo `TIMESTAMP` o `DATETIME` y sirve para marcar cuando la fila es editada/creada.

Comment: Si ya le asigne `NULL` como predeterminado y aún regresa el `{respuesta: "error: Field 'editado' doesn't have a default value"}`, tengo que esperar un rato a que se "actualice" (estoy utilizando WAMP)

Comment: No creo. Por favor muestra lo que imprime un `SHOW CREATE TABLE admins;` ejecutado en la base de datos.

Comment: Lo pondré en un edit, para que se lea mejor. Listo, ya esta en la pregunta.

Comment: En ese caso el problema sería con `nivel` el cual está en la misma situación en que estaba `editado`, o sea, no admite nulos y no es mencionado en tu `INSERT INTO`... cuando un campo no es mencionado en un `INSERT` el sistema intentará asignarle `NULL` cuando no tiene un valor por defecto. En el caso de `nivel` el insert va a rebotar también.

Comment: ¡FUNCIONÓ!, muchas gracias, enserio.

Comment: Me alegro. Otra cosa, para ser más coherente, conviene que `editado`  en vez de en vez de `DEFAULT NULL` tenga por defecto esto : `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` de ese modo adquirirá como valor la marca del tiempo en que se creó esa fila.

Comment: Gracias, de hecho si lo acabo de cambiar... casi no uso stack, ¿pongo yo la respuesta a mi misma pregunta a pesar de que tu me diste la respuesta?

Comment: Escribiré una respuesta con algunas explicaciones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero que debe quedar zanjado es que `insert_id` es un método de la conexión, no de la sentencia. [El Manual de PHP es muy claro en eso: **`mysqli::$insert_id`**](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.insert-id.php) donde `mysqli` representa al objeto conexión, el cual es `$conn` en tu caso.

Luego, hemos logrado imprimir el motivo del error, haciendo esto:

```
 ...
 }else{
  $respuesta = array(
    'respuesta' => 'error: '.$conn->error;
  );
```

el cual es el siguiente:

> Field 'editado' doesn't have a default value"

Cuando haces inserciones en una tabla, las columnas que no reciben valores específicos en esa consulta adquieren :

- *a*. su valor por defecto en caso de tenerlo
- *b.* o `NULL` si no tienen valor por defecto

En el caso *b* puede haber un conflicto, que es lo que sin duda debe estar ocurriendo con tu columna `editado`: la misma **no tiene declarado un valor por defecto ni tampoco admite valores nulos**. Al no ser mencionada en el `INSERT INTO ...` se le intentará asignar `NULL` y la inserción no será posible porque viola la restricción `NOT NULL` que tiene esa columna.

**Soluciones**:

*a*. Darle un valor por defecto con:

```
ALTER TABLE admins 
MODIFY COLUMN editado DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

---

*b*. Incluirla en la sentencia de inserción asignándole un valor:

```
INSERT INTO admins (usuario, nombre, password, editado) VALUES (?, ?, ?, NOW())
```

---

*c.* Modificar `editado` para que admita nulos.

---

> ***a.***  es la solución más razonable, resolviendo el problema de raíz.

Nótese que tienes el mismo problema con tu columna `nivel`, la misma no admite nulos, por tanto, debería tener un valor por defecto (`0` por ejemplo)  o bien debes modificarla para que admita nulos o no podrás olvidarla nunca en un `INSERT INTO ...` :-)  Pequeños detalles que se escapan pero que son muy importantes.

Espero que sea de utilidad.