# No me pone Bien la fecha

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, date

mi duda es tengo contratado mi hosting
pero cuando subo mi pagina al darle un insert a las tablas yo tengo una columna de fecha la cual es
date
en php lo tengo como insert con NOW()
ENTONCES al momento de guardar me pone mal la fecha y la hora

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<?php
     date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');

    include ("../conecta.php");
    session_start();

    if (!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
    header("Location: index.php");
       echo'<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Debes iniciar sesion");
    window.location.href="index.php";
    </script>';

    exit();
  }

    $usu=$_SESSION['usuario'];
     $nom=$_SESSION['usuario'];
 

  

 $departamento=$_POST['departamento'];
 $periodo=$_POST['periodo'];
 $grupo=$_POST['grupo'];
 $ua=$_POST['ua'];
 $tipo=$_POST['tipo'];
 $nivel=$_POST['nivel'];
 $coffa=$_POST['coffa'];
 $edi=$_POST['edi'];
 $edd=$_POST['edd'];


$query ="INSERT INTO datos  
(id_prof,departamento,periodo,grupo,ua,tipo,nivel,coffa,edi,edd,fecha)
VALUES
 ('".$_SESSION['usuario']."','$departamento','$periodo', '$grupo','$ua','$tipo','$nivel','$coffa','$edi','$edd', NOW())";
$respuesta=mysqli_query($conexion,$query);

if(!$respuesta)
{

   die("Ocurrio un Error".mysqli_error($conexion));
}
  else
  {

   echo "<center><h1 ><br><img src=../img/logos.png width=320 height=130><br>Datos Registrados

   <a href='index.php'></a></h1></center>";
  }
/*var_dump($query);*/
    
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

                  <html>
                      <head>
                         <meta charset="UTF-8">
                            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximun-scale=1.0, minimun-scale=1.0">
                            <title> Cerrar sesión</title>     
                           <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/estilos.css">

<script>
    function TiempoActividad()
    {
    setTimeout("DestruirSesion()",  120000);//Original tiene esté tiempo son 2 minutos
    }
    function DestruirSesion()
    {
    location.href = "../cerrarsesion.php";
    }
</script> 

                         </head>

                  <header><div id="cerrar1"><a href="../cerrarsesion.php">Cerrar Sesi&oacute;n</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div><br><br>
                </header>

             <body onload="TiempoActividad()">       
                   <center>

                    <h3>Recuerda Imprimir o Guardar su Acuse</h3><br>
                 <button> <a href="imprimegenerales.php?id=<?php echo $usuario['id'] ?>" target="_blank">
          <img src="../img/impresora.png" width="70" height="70"><img src="../img/guardar.png" width="70" height="70"></button></a><br><br><br>

                      <h3>Cargar Reportes en Formato PDF</h3>
                      <img src="https://www.gifsanimados.org/data/media/111/flecha-imagen-animada-0311.gif" width="30" height="30">
                          <a href="index.php"><br><br>
                            <input type="submit" class="boton-enviar" value="Cargar Archivos PDF"></a>  
                             </center><br>
                            <a href="index.html">
                          <!--<input type="submit" class="boton-regresar" value="    Salir    ">
                       </a><br><br>-->
                    
    </body>     
</html>
```

dejo el código el cual si me sirve en local pero cuando lo subo al servidor de hostinger
me aparece diferente todas las fechas

Comment: Mal, la coloca adelantada o atrasada con respecto a la actual?

Comment: Procura definir "mal".

Comment: Si lo que quieres es que en la columna `fecha`  se agregue el momento actual cuando se crea un registro, puedes definir esa columna del tipo `DATETIME` y darle por defecto el valor de `CURRENT TIME_STAMP`, luego en el `INSERT` no pasas valor para esa columna y cada fila se creará con el momento actual en que ocurrió la inserción. [Aquí tienes un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo por definición de tabla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/185689/29967). Antes de usar `ALTER TABLE` haz un backup de la tabla por seguridad. Si quieres otra zona horaria la estableces en el script de inserción y listo.

Answer (score 2):

El problema que tienes es que `NOW()` es una función de `MySQL` por lo que no esta tomando la zona horaria de `PHP`

Para tomar la zona horaria de 'America/Mexico_City' en `PHP` podrias hacer lo siguiente

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');

$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

//Tu query quedaría así:

$query ="INSERT INTO datos (id_prof,departamento,periodo,grupo,ua,tipo,nivel,coffa,edi,
edd,fecha) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['usuario']."','$departamento','$periodo', '$grupo','$ua',
'$tipo','$nivel','$coffa','$edi','$edd', '$now')";
$respuesta=mysqli_query($conexion,$query);



//date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); El formato es el siguiente:
//Y = año en 4 dígitos
//m = mes 2 dígitos
//d = día 2 dígitos
//H = hora en formato de 24 horas
//i = minutos en 2 dígitos
//s = segundos en 2 dígitos
```

Mas información: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date.php

Answer (score 1):

Si el problema es que aparece la fecha con hora, puedes usar alguna de estas opciones para mantener la visualizacion en ambos lados:

- Asegurarte de que la columna `fecha` sea de tipo DATE y no DATETIME en el hosting. Si es de tipo DATE no mostrara hora.
- AL insertar los datos usa `CURDATE()` (fecha actual sin hora) en vez de `NOW()`.
- Al mostrar los resultados, formatea la fecha usando la funcion `date()` : Ejemplo `date('Y-m-d',$fecha)`

SI el problema es que las ***horas no coinciden*** al mostrar la misma informacion de la base de datos, significa que localmente o en el sistema remoto la zona horaria no esta configurada de la misma manera, ya sea en PHP o MySQL

- Revisa el valor de zona horaria de MySQL `time_zone`: `SELECT @@global.time_zone;`
- Deberian mostrarse iguales, de otro modo la conversion de horas pueden ser distintas. Si este es el caso, asegurate de ejecutar `SET GLOBAL time_zone = ‘-5:00’;` al iniciar la conexion Mysql.
- Igualmente revisa si efectivamente la zona horaria fue configurada revisa el valor de `date_offset_get(new DateTime);` para confirmar que efectivamente se aplico el ajuste de zona horaria